# background-image property

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the `background-image` property to work. I am trying to add images to the borders of my button, but it is not working. Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/Bchga/.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn">Image Borders</a>
```

**CSS**

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #67b8de;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png") no-repeat right bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `background-image` rule also contains values for `background-repeat` and `background-position`. Separate them (or you can put the colour in too and use the `background` shorthand):

```css
background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right bottom;
```

Comment: @htmltroll: That’s just the matter of your image being way too big. Do you want to scale it?

Comment: I thought about the same, but sticking everything to a single `background` property. Anyway, it doesn't work either.

Comment: I think the image extention is not good. Try just a png file: http://jsfiddle.net/Bchga/ with this, it works, maybe the https is not working too ...

Answer (score 1):

Okay I went over the documentation on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds

**The new CSS**

```
.btn {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    /* Notice that I list all the images */
    background: url("../img/border-top-left.png"), url("../img/border-top-right.png"),
                url("../img/border-bottom-left.png"), url("../img/border-bottom-right.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
    background-color: #67b8de;
}
```

You will notice that I use the `background:` property, you can also use the `background-image` property, thanks for the tip *minitech*. You also should notice that you can't just specify individual image is you want to target all the corners of the button. Example:

```
background-image: url("../img/border-blah-blah.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
```

This will not target all of your corners, but only one corner will be targeted this is because of the cascade it will overwrite the previous rule, that's why you have to input the sources for all your images at once and then target them. Also you should put the `background-color` property last, because the color won't be applied if it is the first rule. I don't know why that happens.

Comment: The reason you had to put `background-color` last here, by the way, is because you used `background` for the first one, which also applies `background-color`. So you can change that to `background-image`, or write `background: #67b8de url(…), url(…), …`.

Answer (score 0):

You background image is too large:
it's working with a background image at 10%..: [Link JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bchga/)

```
    background: #ff8844 url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Small-city-symbol.svg/348px-Small-city-symbol.svg.png") 10%
```